# AJAX client side validation is not getting called properly

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have written this ajax function, where i have given form validation for each inputs, problem is when i press button it doesn't check validation and perform post method with required data successfully.It simply not going to client side validation part, thats why going straight to my post method call and then redirecting to my respective redirected_url. May i know how to correct it?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn,.apply1,.btn_mt,.payment').click(function() {
    if (formValidate()) {
      alert('clicked')
      $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/payment',
        data: {
          'card-name': $('#id_card_name').val(),
          'card-number': $('#id_card_number').val(),
          'card-ex-month': $('#id_card_expiry').val(),
          'card-security-code': $('#id_security_code').val(),
          csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
        },
        success: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
          alert(response.card);
          var res = $.parseJSON(response);
          if (res.data.card.status == "succeeded") {
            window.location = res.redirect_url
          }
        }
      })
    }
  })
})

function formValidate() {
  alert('in')
  var isValid = true;
  if ($('#id_card_name').val() == "") {
    isValid = false
    $('#lcredit-card-paypal').html('Please Enter Name On Card')
  } else {
    if (!(/^[a-z][a-z\s]*$/.test($('#id_card_name').val()))) {
      isValid = false;
      $('#credit-card-paypal').html('Please Enter Valid Name On Card')
    }
  }
  if ($('#id_card_number').val() == "") {
    isValid = false
    $('#credit-card-paypal').html('Please Enter Number On Card')
  } else {
    if (!(/^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|[25][1-7][0-9]{14}|6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}|(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11})$/.test($('#id_card_name').val()))) {
      isValid = false;
      $('#credit-card-paypal').html('Please Enter Valid Number On Card')
    }
  }
  if ($('#id_card_expiry').val() == "") {
    isValid = false
    $('#credit-card-paypal').html('Please Enter Expiry Month & Year')
  } else {
    if (!(/^\d{2}\/\d{4}$/.test($('#id_card_expiry').val()))) {
      isValid = false;
      $('#credit-card-paypal').html('Please Enter Valid xpiry Month & Year')
    }
  }


  if ($('#id_security_code').val() == '') {
    isValid = false
    $('#credit-card-paypal').html('Please Enter PSecurity Code')
  } else {
    if (!(/^[0-9]{3,4}$/.test($('#id_security_code').val()))) {
      isValid = false;
      $('#credit-card-paypal').html('Please Enter Valid Expiry Month & Year')
    }
  }
  return isValid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/payment" method="post">
  <div id="credit-card-paypal"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 input_mb">
    <label>Name on Card</label>
    <input id="id_card_name" class="form-control" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Full name as display on card">
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 input_mb">
    <label>Credit Card Number</label>
    <input id="id_card_number" class="form-control" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Enter Card Number">
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 input_mb">
    <label>Expiry</label>
    <input id="id_card_expiry" class="form-control" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Ex: 06/2023">
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 input_mb">
    <label>Security Code</label>
    <input id="id_security_code" class="form-control" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Ex: XXX8">
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-m col-xs-6 input_mb">
    <button class="btn apply1 btn_mt payment" type="button">PAY $139</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Make sure no one of those buttons `.btn,.apply1,.btn_mt,.payment`  have `type="submit"`, if they have replace them by `type="button"`

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki No button type is `button` not submit.

Comment: Show us you HTML code please, try to provide a live example that reproduces your issue.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki yes, have updated question with html , please have a look

Comment: Check the snippet in your question, I see that the `in` alert is reached

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki hi,thanks for your answer..i have solved it, by changing validation form name, it was conflicting with other validation function names. btw my validations are now shoing problem, in security code validation it doesnt go to else part?

Comment: You're welcome, update the code in your question so I can check the last version of your code.